Accessing subclasses of a Class in Java
I am new to Java and currently learning about SOLID principles and design patterns. While trying to fully adhere to the OCP (Open/Closed Principle) and the Prototype Design Pattern, I encountered an issue: I have to modify the Main class whenever I add a new shape class, which extends the Forme abstract class.
Here is the Main Java code:
import java.util.*;

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        Palette pal = new Palette();
        Editeur editeur = new Editeur(pal);
        
        System.out.print("\nAdd Circle (0/1)? ");
        int input = scanner.nextInt();
        if (input == 1) {
            pal.ajouter(new Cercle(null));
        }
        
        System.out.print("Add Triangle (0/1)? ");
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        if (input == 1) {
            pal.ajouter(new Triangle(null));
        }
        
        System.out.print("Add Rectangle (0/1)? ");
        input = scanner.nextInt();
        if (input == 1) {
            pal.ajouter(new Rectangle(null));
        }
        
        editeur.dessiner();
        editeur.afficherDessin();
        scanner.close();
    }    
}

I tried to find a way to dynamically handle this, similar to Python's .__subclasses__() method, which retrieves all subclasses of a class. However, Java does not have a built-in equivalent. I also came across external libraries like Reflections, but they require additional dependencies in the environment.
Is there a way to implement this functionality (adding new shapes without even changing the main code) without relying on external libraries?

Short of reimplementing the Reflections library yourself?  No.  Java is generally hostile to trying to do things like this.  (A good thing, too; this is a design smell.)

Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
It is unclear what you are asking or what the problem is.
Please [edit] your question to include a more detailed description of the problem you have.

This question is similar to: How can I get a list of all the implementations of an interface programmatically in Java?. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.

@smallpepperz found a good answer (Java SPI). Unfortunately the question was a one-liner and quite general, and I like this one with reference to Python's subclasses, general design principles.

There is one general mechanism for discovery, Java SPI (Service Provider Interface). You can have even multiple and separate libraries (jars) that state that they provide one or more implementation classes of an interface.
Notewothy Baeldung blogs about Java SPI. (Not affiliated.)
In this way database drivers are discovered in JDBC and java.sql.Connection implementations created.
In your case:
An API jar (for instance)
package forme.api;
public interface Forme {
}

For form implementors a utility abstract base class
package forme.internal;
public abstract class AbstractForme implements Forme {
}

Implementations
package forme.impl.basic:
public class Cercle implements Forme
public class Ellipse extends AbstractForme

with a text file on the class path in the jar
META-INF/services/forme.api.Forme
forme.impl.basic.Cercle
forme.impl.basic.Ellipse

package forme.impl.specielle;
public class KleinBouteille implements Forme

with a text file on the class path in the jar
META-INF/services/forme.api.Forme
forme.impl.speciell.KleinBouteille

Your Main usage
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // Do a lookup of all Forme providers
        ServiceLoader<Forme> loader = ServiceLoader.load(Forme.class);
        List<Forme> formes = new ArrayList<>();
        loader.forEach(formes::add);

